# PHP replace all symbol in the beginning and the end of string or array

Tags: php

Hello I have this variable

```
$str="101,102,103,104,105,@,106@107"
//or array
$str_arr = array(  0 => '101',  1 => '102',  2 => '103',  3 => '104',
                   4 => '105',  8 => '@' ,  9 => '106@ 107');
```

I want to remove the symbol @ between comma

The symbol may be /,\,-,| not comma
The symbol between number is correct, so it remains (key 9)

I do not know, if I had these cases but I will study it

```
$str="101,102,103,104,105@, 106" // One of the symbols  in the end of number
$str="101,102,103,104,105,@106" // One of the symbols in the  the beginning of number
```

**This is The different possibilities**

```
$str="101,102,103,/,104|,@105,106@107" //replace all symbol in the beginning and the end of number not betwwen number
```

this is result

```
$str="101,102,103,104,105,106@107";
```

Thanks

Comment: So [explode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) on the comma to an array; [array_walk()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) or [array_map()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) with a callback to [trim()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) the beginning/end characters that you don't want; and then [array_filter()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to remove any entries that have been left empty; before [implode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) back to a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the string to array using explode by `,`. Parse the array using `foreach` loop. `trim()` the `@` or any set of characters like `@-|\/` from the beginning and end of every string, then check for empty values and push non empty values to the `$arr` array. Then you can join the array into a string using `implode`. You can do it like this:

```
 $arr = array();
 $str="101,102,103,104,105,@,106@107";
 $str = explode(',', $str);
 foreach($str as $s){
     $s = trim($s, "@-|\/");
     if(!empty($s)){
        $arr[] = $s;
     }
 }
$final_str = implode(',', $arr);        
var_dump($final_str);
```

Comment: we can use trim  regular expression to detect symbol

Comment: we can use trim  regular expression to detect symbol ?  because 
The symbol may be / or \or  -or  | in the end or beginning of number

Comment: @logitech2004 - Read the php docs for trim(); it allows you to list a set of characters that you want to trim, not simply a singe character